# How do I statically link SDL2 in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, sdl-2, static-linking

I'm new to linking in general, how do I link SDL2 statically without having to have DDL's?

I have seen a couple examples online, but they aren't easy to understand and follow.

also I've read somewhere online that you have to statically build DDL's into lib libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build SDL2 by yourself as a static library.

---

First, clone the [SDL Repo](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL), preferably a stable tag, latest one being [2.28.1](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/tree/release-2.28.1) at the time of writing.

---

Then, open the SDL Solution located at `<SDL Repo>/VisualC/SDL.sln`.

Once the solution has opened, right click the SDL2 project (on the right tab) and select Properties:

[image: Picture of the VS project being right clicked]

---

A new window will open, change `Configuration` to `All configurations` and `Platform` to `All Platforms`:

[image: Picture describing the above sentence]

---

Then, in `Configuration Properties`-> `General`, change `Configuration Type` from `Dynamic Library (.dll)` to `Static library (.lib)`:

[image: Picture of the SDL2 Project properties with arrows to guide where to click]

---

Click `OK` to save your changes and close the window:

[image: Picture describing the above sentence]

---

Now, you can set the target platform of your choice and hit `Build` -> `Build SDL2` to build SDL2 as a static library:

[image: .]
[image: .]

Do **NOT** Build the entire solution, as it will build the test projects, which will fail.

---

You will find built `.lib` files in the output folder that corresponds to your target configuration:

[image: .]

Do note that there won't be any DLL, as statically linking libraries using visual studio requires a `.lib` (and not a `.dll`, as those are for dynamic linking).

---

Now, just follow the usual installation tutorial for VS (that normally makes you dynamically link SDL2), but copy `SDL2.lib`, `SDL2main.lib` and `SDL2test.lib` over the ones found in the dynamic link package.

You can then remove the DLLs.

Do not that for your project to build, you will need to statically link `winmm.lib`, `setupapi.lib`, `version.lib` and `Imm32.lib` to it.

For this, open the save property window as you opened earlier, but for your project that uses SDL2, and go in `Configuration Properties` -> `Linker` -> `Input` and add the aforementionned filenames into `Additional Dependencies`.

Your project should now build, with a static SDL2 included.

---

Note: If you use SDL2 modules like SDL2_image, SDL2_ttf, SDL2_mixer, etc, you will need to statically build them as well, using the same method.

Comment: perfectly documented, thanks!

Comment: @bpss32423 Glad I was able to help you! And thanks for accepting my answer ^^